# XML multiline comments in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio-2010, comments

`<br/>`and  `<para>` tags will works on C# code, but not working on javascript?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: are you asking about C# XML comments (used for documentation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`para` will work if you install JScript Editor Extensions

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed